# How to change the highlight color in Eagle when using the show command?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-layers

I want to use "show GND" and have everything highlighted show up purple. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a track by clicking on it.

Go to "options", choose "set" and there you should find a slider that can be used to set the brightness of anything that is highlighted.

You can also (within that area) select "high contrast" and adjust the slider to give different colours. You can choose purple.